# Installing drivers into docker image for kubernetes deployment

Tags: ubuntu, docker, kubernetes, drivers

I am accessing a USB Card reader on an Ubuntu 18.04 node.  Here is what is installed on the Ubuntu 18.04 node to access the USB Card reader:

```
sudo apt-get install pcscd 
sudo apt-get install pcsc-tools // same as   pcsc-lite                                    
// For OMNIKEY for driver Then unpack the   file and run the installer:
cd /home/cccam/ifdokccid_lnx_x64-3.7.0/ 
chmod 755 install
sudo ./install
javax.cardio // so I need Java OpenJDK 8 64 bit
```

So from Kubernetes node I am creating hostPath volume to load the /dev tree.  I am told that for non-kernel drivers like the Card reader driver I need to install in container as well as have installed on the host. How exactly do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you own the image you want to run in your container you can simply modify that image and perform driver installation in the Dockerfile. That way the drivers will be installed in the container OS. You can do so like you run `pip install stuff` when you want to run Python scripts, or you `apt-get install modules` during container creation. Compile/install drivers is also an option.

Also, you way want to try [Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) if the above would not be good enough for you. However, it might not be the better option here.

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Have you managed to make it work?